# I'm not able to fetch a single student from the in-memory web api Angular

Tags: angular, crud, in-memory-database

I'm building a CRUD app with Angular for my project. I followed the angular-tour-of-heores tutorial and did mine with students. I started with the mock-students as database (storage) and later moved to the in memory but i have issues fetching a single student, i can fetch all the students but when i click on a particular student's info to view that particular student's info in a new component, it doesn't fetch.

#### This is the student.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from './Student';
import { Students } from './mock-students';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentService {
  private StudentsUrl = 'api/Students';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /* GET Students from the server */
  getStudents(): Observable<Student[]> {
    return this.http.get<Student[]>(this.StudentsUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => alert('Fetched Students')),
        catchError(this.handleError<Student[]>('getStudents', []))
      );
  }

  /** GET student by matNo. Will 404 if id not found */
  getStudent(matNo: String): Observable<Student> {
    const url = `${this.StudentsUrl}/${matNo}`;
    return this.http.get<Student>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => alert(`Fetched Student matNo=${matNo}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Student>(`getStudent matNo=${matNo}`))
    );
  }

  // Get Student by matNo
  // getStudent(matNo: String): Observable<Student> {
  //   const student = Students.find(s => s.matNo === matNo)!;
  //   return of(student);
  // }

  /**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 *
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      alert(`${operation} failed! : ${error.message}`)

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

#### This is the student-detail.component.ts file (it displays a particular student's info):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../Student';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-result',
  templateUrl: './student-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-result.component.css']
})
export class StudentResultComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() student?: Student;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private studentService: StudentService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStudent();
  }
  
  getStudent(): void {
    const matNo = String(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('matNo'));
    this.studentService.getStudent(matNo)
      .subscribe(student => this.student = student);
  }

  goBack(): void{
    this.location.back()
  }

}
```

#### This is the in-memory-data.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Course } from './Course';
import { Student } from './Student';
import { Score } from './Score';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {

    const Students: Student[] = [
      { studentName: "John Doe", matNo: 'SC20A392' },
      { studentName: "Dick Dick Bobi", matNo: 'SC20B101' },
      { studentName: "Leslie Apple", matNo: 'SC20C123' },
      { studentName: "Paul Paul", matNo: 'SC20C699' },
      { studentName: "Vanessa Glory", matNo: 'SC19A100' },
      { studentName: "Micheal Angel", matNo: 'SC20B056' },
      { studentName: "Rob Dickson", matNo: 'SC20B112' },
      { studentName: "Jane Mellisa", matNo: 'SC20C222' },
      { studentName: "Vanelle Linda", matNo: 'SC20B419' }
    ];

    const Courses: Course[] = [
      { cseCode: "CSC407", cseTitle: 'Programming Language Paradigm' },
      { cseCode: "CSC405", cseTitle: 'Artificial Intelligence' },
      { cseCode: "CSC413", cseTitle: 'Mobile App Development' },
      { cseCode: "CSC403", cseTitle: 'Numerical Analysis' },
      { cseCode: "MAT201", cseTitle: 'Mathematics' },
      { cseCode: "ENG101", cseTitle: 'English' },
      { cseCode: "FRE101", cseTitle: 'French' },
      { cseCode: "CVE100", cseTitle: 'Civics' },
    ];

    const Scores: Score[] = [
      // student 1
      { matNo: 'SC20A392', cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "22", examMark: "56"},
      { matNo: "SC20A392", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "14", examMark: "30" },
      { matNo: "SC20A392", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "17", examMark: "27" },
      { matNo: "SC20A392", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "19", examMark: "40" },
      { matNo: "SC20A392", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "25", examMark: "62" },
      { matNo: "SC20A392", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "10", examMark: "39" },
      
      // student 2
      { matNo: "SC20B101", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "26", examMark: "51" },
      { matNo: "SC20B101", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "9", examMark: "28" },
      { matNo: "SC20B101", cseCode: 'MAT201', cseTitle: "Mathematics", caMark: "27", examMark: "57" },
      { matNo: "SC20B101", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "22", examMark: "37" },
      { matNo: "SC20B101", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "10", examMark: "12" },
      { matNo: "SC20B101", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "20", examMark: "41" },
      
      // student 3
      { matNo: "SC20C123", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "28", examMark: "67" },
      { matNo: "SC20C123", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "14", examMark: "30" },
      { matNo: "SC20C123", cseCode: 'MAT201', cseTitle: "Mathematics", caMark: "15", examMark: "60" },
      { matNo: "SC20C123", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "29", examMark: "57" },
      { matNo: "SC20C123", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "25", examMark: "62" },
      { matNo: "SC20C123", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "10", examMark: "39" },

      // student 4
      { matNo: "SC20C699", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "30", examMark: "70" },
      { matNo: "SC20C699", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "24", examMark: "68" },
      { matNo: "SC20C699", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "27", examMark: "55" },
      { matNo: "SC20C699", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "29", examMark: "59" },
      { matNo: "SC20C699", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "27", examMark: "62" },
      { matNo: "SC20C699", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "19", examMark: "59" },

      // student 5
      { matNo: "SC19A100", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "20", examMark: "40" },
      { matNo: "SC19A100", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "14", examMark: "30" },
      { matNo: "SC19A100", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "17", examMark: "27" },
      { matNo: "SC19A100", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "19", examMark: "40" },
      { matNo: "SC19A100", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "25", examMark: "62" },
      { matNo: "SC19A100", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "10", examMark: "39" },

      // student 6
      { matNo: "SC20B056", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "16", examMark: "38" },
      { matNo: "SC20B056", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "4", examMark: "22" },
      { matNo: "SC20B056", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "27", examMark: "47" },
      { matNo: "SC20B056", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "9", examMark: "16" },
      { matNo: "SC20B056", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "28", examMark: "70" },
      { matNo: "SC20B056", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "5", examMark: "49" },

      // student 7
      { matNo: "SC20B112", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "13", examMark: "45" },
      { matNo: "SC20B112", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "14", examMark: "50" },
      { matNo: "SC20B112", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "23", examMark: "48" },
      { matNo: "SC20B112", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "30", examMark: "50" },
      { matNo: "SC20B112", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "25", examMark: "12" },
      { matNo: "SC20B112", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "12", examMark: "34" },

      // student 8
      { matNo: "SC20C222", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "21", examMark: "60" },
      { matNo: "SC20C222", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "18", examMark: "54" },
      { matNo: "SC20C222", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "14", examMark: "49" },
      { matNo: "SC20C222", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "20", examMark: "46" },
      { matNo: "SC20C222", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "23", examMark: "58" },
      { matNo: "SC20C222", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "24", examMark: "50" },

      // student 9
      { matNo: "SC20B419", cseCode: 'CSC407', cseTitle: "Programming Language Paradigm", caMark: "10", examMark: "50" },
      { matNo: "SC20B419", cseCode: 'CSC405', cseTitle: "Artificial Intelligence", caMark: "15", examMark: "41" },
      { matNo: "SC20B419", cseCode: 'CSC413', cseTitle: "Mobile App Development", caMark: "17", examMark: "37" },
      { matNo: "SC20B419", cseCode: 'CSC403', cseTitle: "Numerical Analysis", caMark: "19", examMark: "49" },
      { matNo: "SC20B419", cseCode: 'ENG101', cseTitle: "English", caMark: "12", examMark: "17" },
      { matNo: "SC20B419", cseCode: 'FRE101', cseTitle: "French", caMark: "17", examMark: "29" },

    ];
    return { Students, Courses,Scores };
  }

  // Overrides the genId method to ensure that a hero always has an id.
  // If the heroes array is empty,
  // the method below returns the initial number (11).
  // if the heroes array is not empty, the method below returns the highest
  // hero id + 1.
  genId(Students: Student[]): String {
    return Students.length > 0 ? "true" : "false";
  }
}
```

#### This is what i get when i run :

[image]

The students data is fetched! And i get this:[image]

But when i click on results button of any student i get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass Data through Router you can do this :

```
getInfo(matNo:number){
    this.router.navigate(['Your Component Rout', { studentMatNo: matNo }]);
}
```

in the other component , for getting data from router you can do this ( you already did it :) ):

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
){}

let updateNumber: number = Number(
    this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('studentMatNo')
);
```

In your code i dont see any `this.router.navigate(['Your Component Rout', { studentMatNo: matNo }]);` did you forgot it ?

Hope it will help you.

Comment: router is not defined